# NullReferenceException problem when loading savegame in XNA 4.0

Tags: xna-4.0

I want to enable my program to load "savegames", and I followed the tutorial on MSDN, but when I run my code, I get the NullReferenceException error. I use an xml file as my savegame data container, and it works, but at this point I have to rebuild my game every time I make some changes to that xml file, and I want to be able to do it during run-time. The xml file is stored in my Content folder.
This is the code of my load method:

```
   public void Otvori()
        {

            IAsyncResult rezultat = device.BeginOpenContainer("OtvaranjeDemo", null, null);           
            rezultat.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

            container = device.EndOpenContainer(rezultat);
            rezultat.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
            if (!container.FileExists(imeDatoteke))
            {
                container.Dispose();
                return;
            }
            Stream stream = container.OpenFile(imeDatoteke, FileMode.Open);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PostavkeStanice));
            PostavkeStanice postavke = (PostavkeStanice)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
            container.Dispose();
        }
```

The compiler throws me the error at this line 
"IAsyncResult rezultat = device.BeginOpenContainer("OtvaranjeDemo", null, null);"

Since this is a method in a game library, I thought it had something to do with variable definition scope, but I declared the variable in the game wide scope, and I use this method inside the Update method, so that should not be the problem?
Do you have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Why dont you use simple file handlers? Is a lot easier than the async ones, and im not sure if you want async here, because, in anyway you cant start the game before the gamestate is loaded(well, i think)

Comment: And by the way... where's 'device' defined? I think its null.

Comment: device, container and imeDatoteke (string containing the name of the save game file) are declared outside the method. Like I said, I used the MSDN tutorial, and it used async, if you have some tutorial that uses file handlers, or solves this problem in any other way please share. I found 2 or 3 tutorials on-line, and they all use async handlers

Comment: Wow, i dont remember to use async when i've used XNA. Try to put a breakline on the method start and see what is the null variable. Well, by the way, can you edit your post and add wherre you're storing your file? Xna content pipeline?

Comment: I did, they all are: rezultat,strem,serializer, postavke, they are all null. That is what I dont understand. This is the declaration part:
 
         `public StorageDevice device;
         public StorageContainer container;
         string imeDatoteke = "Postavke.xml";`

Comment: Have you tried to e

Comment: Have you tried to just : MemoryStream stream = OpenFile("Content/filename.xml", OpenMode.Read); ? Then reading it as a xml is a trivial task.

Comment: Oh and take a look, every object in C# start as null! Until you use some method to fill it, or make a variable = new type(); it would still be null. It isnt equal C++

Comment: Yes I've tried to use "= new", compiler throws me an error "The type...has no constructor defined". As for, MemoryStream, I tried it, gives me the same error

Comment: This is because i've said 'fill with methods, OR new instance' Memory Streams should be initialized with OpenFile or with other Stream allocation Method. But also, i'm pretty sure that there is a MemoryStream(stream) constructor... are you doing it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a device first using [StorageDevice.BeginShowSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb199086.aspx) In the Async callback of that method, you can assign the device to your variable. Only then can you call methods on it.
See [Getting a StorageDevice Asyncronously (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203920.aspx).

---

I suggest using the [EasyStorage](https://github.com/nickgravelyn/EasyStorage) helper classes that encapsulates a lot of the setup of loading/saving.

Comment: Shor answer for what i've trying to explain in the comments haha, thanks :D

Comment: Can the methods used in windows forms be used to solve this problem, or does it conflict with some XNA restrictions. Also, can I show an OpenFile dialog in the game and how?

Comment: Whether there are restrictions depends on your target platform (PC/xbox). Given that games run in a continual loop, opening the openfile dialog would need some fancy coding to get it to work. XNA (and games in general) work differently to an event driven system like winforms.

Comment: Well, this program will run only on PC. What is the alternative to OpenFile dialog?

Comment: Thinking about it, you might be able to get the OpenFileDialog to work, altough the game window might go a bit weird. Add a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly and namespace.

Comment: So fully qualify anything with issues then. The problem will be that there are things in the System.Windows.Forms namespace with the same name as some XNA classes, so don't add `using System.Windows.Forms` and use `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`

Comment: Do you know some links that have code samples on this matter. I already tried the MSDN and few others, but obviously I'm implementing it wrong since none of my attempts produce the result I need. I only asked about the OpenFileDialog because I worked with it in my Windows forms projects, and it seemed like a good alternative. The problem is I never worked with opening files from XNA so I'm a bit lost in the terminology. Thanks again for helping me

Comment: You will have to handle displaying a list of files and allowing the user to choose them yourself unfortunately.